# Database Lockes in Antergos

Tags: pacman, antergos

I am trying to update my packages through the graphic package manager.

I get the error `unable to lock database`. Everything on the internet says that if this error occurs, a `db.lck` file should appear in the `/var/lib/pacman` folder. But it isn't there.

If I try to update with the command line, it works great:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Same here --  note that if you click 'ok' and then 'apply' again - it will work.   This only started happening recently and I assume is related to the 'update' GUI rather then pacman..